# Firefox: Limit add-ons like Flash

Tags: firefox, flash

There are some sites that I use that require flash, but generally I would rather not use flash at all while working on the web.  Is there some way to instruct Firefox to only permit flash use by certain sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Flash Block](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashblock/) Firefox extension does exactly this. It starts out by blocking all Flash content, then you can build a whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [AdBlock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/). You could block all `*.swf` content or indeed all `object`/`embed` tags etc. It adds a toolbar icon next to your address bar which lets you temporarily disable the filtering or alternatively use a Whitelist.